# Show that $\left \| L \right \|\leq (\sum_{i,j=1}^n|l_{ij}|^2)^{1/2}$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Let $L=(l_{ij})$ be $2\times 2$ matrix, and define
$$
\left \| L \right \|:=\operatorname{sup}\left \{ \left \| \begin{pmatrix}
l_{11}x_1 + l_{12}x_2\\ 
l_{21}x_1 + l_{22}x_2
\end{pmatrix} \right \|_2:\left \| (x_1,x_2) \right \|_2\leq 1 \right \}.
$$
How to show that $\left \| L \right \|\leq (\sum_{i,j=1}^n|l_{ij}|^2)^{1/2}$? In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Special_cases), it says "**This inequality can be derived from the fact that the trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues**". Could one do a direct calculation without using this fact? What I tried is:
$$
\left \| \begin{pmatrix}
l_{11}x_1 + l_{12}x_2\\ 
l_{21}x_1 + l_{22}x_2
\end{pmatrix} \right \|_2^2={\color{red}{\left | l_{11}x_1 + l_{12}x_2 \right |^2}}+{\color{blue}{\left | l_{21}x_1 + l_{22}x_2 \right |^2}}\\
={\color{red}{\left | l_{11}x_1\right |^2+2\Re(l_{11}x_1\overline{l_{12}x_2}) + \left | l_{12}x_2\right |^2}}+{\color{blue}{\left | l_{21}x_1\right |^2+2\Re(l_{21}x_1\overline{l_{22}x_2}) + \left | l_{22}x_2\right |^2}}\\
=(\left | l_{11}\right |^2+\left | l_{21}\right |^2)\left | x_1 \right |^2+(\left | l_{12}\right |^2+\left | l_{22}\right |^2)\left | x_2 \right |^2+2\Re(l_{11}x_1\overline{l_{12}x_2}) +2\Re(l_{21}x_1\overline{l_{22}x_2}).
$$
What would the next step be? I think this expression must somehow be in terms of $\left \| (x_1,x_2) \right \|_2=\left ( \left | x_1 \right |^2+\left | x_2 \right |^2 \right )^{1/2}$ so that I can do $\leq 1$ at it.

The next step, is what I think is:
$$
\leq (\left | l_{11}\right |^2+\left | l_{21}\right |^2+\left | l_{12}\right |^2+\left | l_{22}\right |^2)(\left | x_1 \right |^2+\left | x_2 \right |^2)+{\color{green}{2\Re(l_{11}x_1\overline{l_{12}x_2}) +2\Re(l_{21}x_1\overline{l_{22}x_2})}}
$$
I do not know what I should do with the green part.

**Edit**: If it is not possible to do the direction calculation, I'll then stick to the **bold text** (in the beginning). Though this does not enlighten me how the inequality exactly is obtained. Could you show me how to use this **fact** to get the estimate?

Comment: No need to answer. (To answer this question, one could simply use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality starting from the first line.)